# Swing's component events

Tags: java, swing, events

How can I find what event a `JComponent` can send?

From JDK documentation is not so clear to find all the event an object sands.

For example a `JButton` send an `ActionEvent` but this is not listed into the API of the `JButton`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of the events that can be sent by a component follow the same pattern.  The component will have a method for each event which looks like addXXXXXListener(XXXX).  Just look for the methods that start with "add" and end with "listener"

Comment: +1 See also `EventListener` http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EventListener.html and `EventListenerList` http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html